# Woocommerce checkout ajax long delay when change of billing address

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a woocommerce site.  When you change the billing address in checkout woocommerce uses ajax to update the shipping cost in the order totals.  However it has recently taken a long time for this process to happen.  Like 15 seconds.

When I checked the Network tab in chrome DevTools and look at the waterfall, all the delay is listed under the Waiting (TTFB) section.  The request url is /?wc-ajax=update_order_review.

What could be causing this delay?

Comment: Depending on your setup, it could be hitting the USPS shipping costs API to get those figures. Can you confirm which shipping method you're using?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt to check my shipping setup.  It was part of the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Upgrading to php 7 dropped the time from 15 seconds to 3 seconds.
2. Deleting all shipping zones (I had a lot set up) dropped the time from 3 seconds to 0.5 seconds.

Now I just need to figure out how to make my shipping work without so many zones.